# Comparing two time values from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to compare two sets of times in order to find out if they're overlapping.  Here is what I have at the moment..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE starttime>='$starttime' AND endtime<='$endtime' AND day='$updateday'";
```

Now this doesn't work as it appears you cant compare time values...so I am completely unsure how this can be done?

Comment: What do your time values look like? (`$starttime`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Datetime fields in MySQL are stored as (for example)

> '2011-05-03 17:01:00'

so you should be able to do something like

```
$starttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

where $timestamp is a timestamp of the time you are concerned about. Then continue with your query.

You can make timestamps by using [mktime()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or [strtotime()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (if starting from a string representation of a time, like from an earlier MySQL query), or just [time()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) for the current time.

Comment: The datatype im using is Time rather than datetime, if that changes anything?  For example this is how I am entering 10AM - 10:00:00

Comment: It shouldn't change anything, you can just do `date('H:i:s', $timestamp)` in PHP to get the right format. What does `day` look like? Is that comparison working too? On the PHP side again you can do `date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)` if `day` in the database is a Date.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using "time" for your datatype. This shouldn't be a problem, since you CAN compare fields using the "time" type. You might want to set your error reporting level to maximum or output your $sql statment just before mysql_query to doublecheck that you are constructing query which can return results at first place. Also check that you have valid dataset for your query in database (has happend to me once while debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use use unix timestamp to compare?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime)>=$starttime AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endtime)<=$endtime AND day='$updateday'";
```

Also I think you're comparing strings, which I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: Doing this will throw out any index on starttime and endtime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the [TIME type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html), your format of "10:00:00" should work.

Not to sound like your mother, but be sure to parameterize your query after you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I did run the SELECT statement on the `phpmyadmin` on the sql before trying to do it on the webpage and was great, the thing is to use it and be thinking in this before:

```
CAST('the_value_you_want_to_be_compared', AS the_type_you_want_to_compare)
```

example:

If you want to compare the date of a day and your table name is activities:

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE date = CAST('2015-10-29', AS date)
```

and so on...

Comment: who wanted to know about date?? dont you see time is mentioned?